# Automatic partition mounting fails after improper shutdown of Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, mount, automount, home-directory

Since I frequently use both Linux and Mac OS X, I am using a shared HFS+ partition as `/home` in Linux and `/Users` in OS X. From day one, OS X was smart enough to automatically mount this partition on boot and, after some minor tweaks, my shared home directory works great.

When my computer is not shutdown properly (e.g. manually restarted after a kernel panic), OS X no longer automatically mounts the partition. This causes the operating system to regenerate a number of settings (e.g. default browser, Finder sidebar) that are not restored after manually mounting my home directory and re-logging.

How can I force OS X to *always* mount my home partition, even if it is after a failed shutdown?